# discord.py mongodb как сделать промокод?

Tags: mongodb, discord.py

хотел спросить у вас как мне решить мою проблему!
Ошибка заключается в том ,что mongodb не видит объект!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Код предоставлен ниже:

```py
    @commands.command(aliases = ['promocod', 'промокод', 'промо'])
    @commands.is_owner()
    async def promo(self, ctx, amount: int = None):
            err = discord.utils.get(self.client.emojis, name='no')
            tru = discord.utils.get(self.client.emojis, name='yes')
        
            if amount is None:
                embed = discord.Embed(
                    title=f'{err} Ошибка!',
                    description = f"Укажите промокод!",
                    colour=err_color
                    )
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            elif self.collservers.insertOne({'guild_id': ctx.guild.id, promocod: ["0"]}) < amount:
                embed = discord.Embed(
                    title=f'{err} Ошибка!',
                    description = f"Промокод не найден!",
                    colour=err_color
                    )
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            elif self.collservers.insertOne({'guild_id': ctx.guild.id, promocod: ["0"]}) > amount:
                embed = discord.Embed(
                    title=f'{err} Ошибка!',
                    description = f"Промокод не найден!",
                    colour=err_color
                    )
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            else:
                eco = self.collservers.find({'guild_id': ctx.guild.id, promocod: ["1"]})
                ispl = self.collservers.find({'guild_id': ctx.guild.id, promocod: ["2"]})
                ecor = self.collection.find_one({'guild_id': ctx.guild.id, "user_id": ctx.author.id})
                ispos = ispl - 1
                ecore = ecor['balance'] + eco
                oipl = self.collservers.update_one({'guild_id': ctx.guild.id}, {'$set':{'balance': "ecore"}})
                splq = self.collservers.update_one({'guild_id': ctx.guild.id, promocod: ["2"]}, {'$set':{"2": "ispos"}})
        
                embed = discord.Embed(
                    title=f'{tru} Успешно!',
                    description = f"Промокод активирован!\nСумма: {self.collservers.find({'guild_id': ctx.guild.id, promocod: ['1']})}",
                    colour=discord.Color.green()
                    )
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Вот код который заносит в MongoDB:

```py
            if not self.collservers.count_documents({"guild_id": ctx.guild.id}):
                post = {
                    "guild_id": ctx.guild.id,
                    "promocod": [
                            promo,
                            amount,
                            ispols
                    ]
                }

                self.collservers.insert_one(post)
```

Answer (score 0):

Помоему у вас проблема в том что promocod не в кавычках, а я так понимаю вы пытаетесь добавлять поле promocod. Попробуйте в запросы в базу поставить кавычки "promocod":

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Gerny, я пробовал уже ставь в кавычки promocod и это не помогло:(